# beamer \usetheme madrid

Tags: beamer, errors, themes

I do not understand why this minimal example does not work with me :

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}  
    toto
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

The error says :

> (/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/beamer/beamerinnerthemerounded.sty
> ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

And the document is corrupted with 4 lines of :

> [colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=true]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your example compiles fine on my computer. Did you check if your LaTeX installation is up to date?

Comment: I think it is up to date :     tex --version ==>> 
"TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020/Arch Linux)
kpathsea version 6.3.2"

latex --version ==>>
"pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Arch Linux)
kpathsea version 6.3.2"

pdflatex --version ==>>
"pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Arch Linux)
kpathsea version 6.3.2"